# Is there a way to export a Google Chrome extension (especially games) into an offline HTML5 app?

Tags: google-chrome, html, google-chrome-extensions, gaming

I want to export Google Chrome extension (especially games) into an offline HTML5 app. I tried exporting the Cut The Rope from location `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gkddaofiamhgfjmaccfcfpfolpgbeomj\16_0`. Then opened index.html but nothing worked. So is it possible to export such apps/games and use the HTML/CSS/JS in any browser.

My question relates first for Cut The Rope only, then for other games.

Comment: Ah. If only HTML5 was universal.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome apps such as the game you mentioned above have been coded to work specifically for Chrome. It is possible for such games to work in different browsers (Not that I have seen it before) but it would required for the entire code to be reviewed and modified as necessary, hence defeating the purpose in my opinion.